# Packaging Electron Apps with external files

Tags: electron

In my Electron application, I have a button in which a user can click which triggers node's child_process and runs an external .jar file in the background:

```
exec(`java -jar encoder.jar -i filein -o fileout`, function(err, stdout, stderr)
```

The actual .jar file is located within the root directory of the project. When running in development mode(unpackaged) this works great. However, when I package it and run the application, I get the following error:

```
There was an error: Error: Unable to access jarfile encoder.jar
```

Am I to assume that everything in the project folder gets packaged when using electron-packager? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you find any answer. Can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61771473/jar-is-not-getting-executed-on-macos-when-packaged-with-electron-packager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look into `process.resourcesPath`